# 2 inputfields to be in Single row ,one rendering other

Tags: visualforce

I tried everything I know to bring Job_Role__c and Job_Role__Other__c in single line . Please let me know if it is possible .[image: singleline]

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >         
    <apex:outputLabel value="Job Role"/>
    <!--<apex:outputPanel id="jobRoleOther"  > -->
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" id="jobRoleOther" >

        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Job_Role__c}" required="True" >  
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="jobRoleOther"/>  </apex:inputField>
        &nbsp;
        <apex:inputField id="jo" value="{!Contact.Job_Role_Other__c}" required="True"  rendered="{!IF((Contact.Job_Role__c='Other'),true,false)}"  /> 
    </apex:panelGrid>
    <!-- </apex:outputPanel> -->
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `StyleClass` with `display:"inline";` for the inputField.

Comment: Thanks Bretto,I am little confused now , I just added in the top        `<style>
    .requiredInput{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>`  and it started coming in single line . I didn't include the style class in inputfield

Comment: Happy for you..